# What are the most important scientific papers about “Adaptive User Interface for mobile devices”?

Tags: mobile

What are the most important scientific papers about "Adaptive User Interface for mobile devices" ?

Shortly, I need to do a research about how to generate AUIs for mobile device depending on user task, device features, context, etc... (I'm in the Artificial Intelligence field).

I need to collect all related works.

Comment: You should try to use a specialised search engine such as Google Scholar (http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Adaptive+User+Interface++for+mobile+devices&btnG=Rechercher&lr=.)  or Microsoft Academic (http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?searchtype=0&query=Adaptive+User+Interface++for+mobile+devices&bouton=hop!).  You can then find new papers using "cite", or "cited by" features on these sites.
Papers from surveys journal (ex: ACM Survey) are often good point to start a bibliography study.

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled upon this article these days:

Eisenstein, J., Vanderdonckt, J., Puerta, A. (2000), Adapting to Mobile Contexts with User-Interface Modeling. Proceedings of Workshop on Mobile Computing Systems and Applications 2000. Monterey, CA: IEEE Press, 7-8 de Dezembro de 2000.

Hope that helps (although it's been a while since you asked)!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few

[Improving Mobile Phone Accessibility with Adaptive User Interfaces](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/15257)

> **Abstract**:Mobile phones have become an important and ubiquitous tool
> for people of all ages and abilities. However, mobile phones can often
> be difficult or impossible to use by people with visual impairments,
> motor impairments, or other disabilities. Although users with
> disabilities are sometimes able to overcome these accessibility
> barriers, it is possible and preferable to design mobile phones that
> adapt to users with a range of abilities. We are investigating the
> problems that people with disabilities encounter when using mobile
> devices, and are developing new techniques to adapt mobile phone user
> interfaces to a user’s abilities. These techniques may increase the
> accessibility of mobile phones for all users.

[Adaptive User Interface for Mobile Devices](https://zaguan.unizar.es/record/1998/files/INPRO--2009-036.pdf)

The abstract is quoted below:

> Adapting a graphical user interface (GUI) to a variety of resources
> with diﬀerent capabilities is one of the most interesting questions of
> today’s mobile computation. The GUI constructed for one application
> should be usable on diﬀerent interactive devices, e.g. WebTV
> terminals, WAP phones or Java-enabled devices. In this paper, we
> discuss existing solutions and present a solution based on mobile
> agents. Mobile agents construct their GUI using third-party eXtensible
> User interface Language (XUL), jXUL middleware and XSL
> transformations. Mobile agents move to host computers and then build
> their GUI, or act as a proxy to devices without suﬃcient processing
> capabilities (e.g., WAP devices). The result is an adaptable GUI
> platform that can be run on multiple devices without modiﬁcations,
> supporting diﬀerent resources and architectures. We show the
> application of this approach by implementing a mobile currency
> converter and survey

[Adaptive user interface for mobile devices (2002)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.140.4996)

> **Abstract**: Adapting a graphical user interface (GUI) to a variety of resources
> with different capabilities is one of the most interesting questions
> of today’s mobile computation. The GUI constructed for one application
> should be usable on different interactive devices, e.g. WebTV
> terminals, WAP phones or Java-enabled devices. In this paper, we
> discuss existing solutions and present a solution based on mobile
> agents. Mobile agents construct their GUI using third-party eXtensible
> User interface Language (XUL), jXUL middleware and XSL
> transformations. Mobile agents move to host computers and then build
> their GUI, or act as a proxy to devices without sufficient processing
> capabilities (e.g., WAP devices). The result is an adaptable GUI
> platform that can be run on multiple devices without modifications,
> supporting different resources and architectures. We show the
> application of this approach by implementing a mobile currency
> converter and survey.

[Toward easy delivery of device-oriented adaptive user interface on mobile devices](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6093396)

> **Abstract**:Due to the heterogeneity of mobile devices, a ubiquitous application is demanded to be developed in various versions to provide
> consistent quality of user experience. Previous studies have been
> proposed to tackle the problem of presenting view across platforms. In
> this work, we propose a framework toward easy delivery of
> device-oriented adaptive user interface on mobile devices. In this
> work, the application is presented in a platform neutral language and
> wrapped with the platform-aware interpreter as an application package.
> On the target device, the platform-aware interpreter can interpret the
> platform-neutral language into a platform-aware application according
> to the device capability and provide appropriate interaction
> alternatives for user selection. As current cross-platform development
> solutions help the developer to cross the programming language gap
> among different platforms, our framework further provides a shortcut
> for easy delivery of device-oriented adaptive user interface on mobile
> devices.

[Adaptive User Interface for Mobile Devices](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/646167.680972)

> **Abstract**: Adapting a graphical user interface (GUI) to a variety of resources with different capabilities is one of the most
> interesting questions of today's mobile computation. The GUI
> constructed for one application should be usable on different
> interactive devices, e.g. WebTV terminals, WAP phones or Java-enabled
> devices. In this paper, we discuss existing solutions and present a
> solution based on mobile agents. Mobile agents construct their GUI
> using third-party eXtensible User interface Language (XUL), jXUL
> middleware and XSL transformations. Mobile agents move to host
> computers and then build their GUI, or act as a proxy to devices
> without sufficient processing capabilities (e.g., WAP devices). The
> result is an adaptable GUI platform that can be run on multiple
> devices without modifications, supporting different resources and
> architectures. We show the application of this approach by
> implementing a mobile currency converter and survey.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the following *paper* titled as *Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation* and available at [ACM's DL](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3134111). The *paper* aims at study the benefits of doing the brain diagnostic on a touch (mobile) device in comparison to the traditional devices (*e.g.*, keyboard and mouse).

[Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3134111)

> Abstract: A fundamental step in medical diagnosis for patient follow-up relies on the ability of radiologists to perform a trusty diagnostic from acquired images. Basically, the diagnosis strongly depends on the visual inspection over the shape of the lesions. As datasets increase in size, such visual evaluation becomes harder. For this reason, it is crucial to introduce easy-to-use interfaces that help the radiologists to perform a reliable visual inspection and allow the efficient delineation of the lesions. We will explore the radiologist's receptivity to the current touch environment solution. The advantages of touch are threefold: (i) the time performance is superior regarding the traditional use, (ii) it has more intuitive control and, (iii) for less time, the user interface delivers more information per action, concerning annotations. From our studies, we conclude that the radiologists still exhibit a resistance to change from traditional to touch based interfaces in current clinical setups.

Francisco M. Calisto, Alfredo Ferreira, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Daniel Gonçalves. 2017. Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces (ISS '17). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 390-395. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3132272.3134111